# How can I insert same data into 2 different tables in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

when I entered first query It was successfully saved to a 1st table. The problem began when i included second query. The problems are:
Data not saving to both table.
Error line is  cmd.executereader().

```vb
Private Sub btnfrmRcptQuerySave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnfrmRcptQuerySave.Click

    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim ctn1 As String = "select * from TicketInfo"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(ctn1)
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim sql1 As String = "insert into TicketInfo(TicketNo, Date, CustNum, CustName, Address, ContNum, Email, AptDate) Values (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", Val(lblRcptQueryNo.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", lblRcptQueryDate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", Val(txtRcptQueryCustNo.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", txtRcptQueryName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", txtRcptQueryAddress.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", txtRcptQueryContact.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", txtRcptQueryEmail.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", DateTimeRcptQuery.Value.Date)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Table 1 saved")

        'Save Data to CleintDetails Table.
        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim ctn2 As String = "select * from CleintDetails"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(ctn2)
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim sql2 As String = "insert into CleintDetails(CustNum, CustName, Address, ContNum, Email) Values (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql2)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", Val(txtRcptQueryCustNo.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", txtRcptQueryName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", txtRcptQueryAddress.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", txtRcptQueryContact.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", txtRcptQueryEmail.Text)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Table 2 saved")


        btnfrmRcptQuerySave.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually it's better to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` for statements that do not return resultsets...

Comment: What is the purpose instantiating the `SELECT ` command and not use it? What error are you getting?

Comment: In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) for ExecuteNonQuery(), it has a paragraph about the return value of this statement "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.". you should check if this return value is according to your expectations.

Comment: *"Error line is cmd.executereader()"*.  Perhaps you could tell us what the error message is on top of where it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

I just started with SQL so I might be wrong, but I would do it like this.

```
Dim SQL_Command As SQLCommand = SQL_Connection.CreateCommand()
SQL_Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 ..."
'Add parameters
SQL_Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

SQL_Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table2 ..."
'no need for adding parameters, we still have them from before as we didn't call SQL_Command.Parameters.Clear() 
SQL_Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a Select command but you never do anything with it. Then you overwrite the `.CommandText` property.

Keep your database objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will handle this even if there is an error.

You can pass the command text and the connection directly to the constructor of the command.

Don't use the old VB6 `Val` method. Use the .net functions (`CInt`, `CDec` etc.).

Don't open your connection until the last minute and close as soon as possible.

Don't use `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
I had to guess at the datatypes and sizes to use with the `.Add` method. Check your database for the actual values.

`.ExecuteReader` is used with Select commands. `.ExecuteNonQuery` is used with Insert, Update and Delete commands.

Don't show message boxes or otherwise interact with the user interface until your connections are closed.

```vb
Private Sub btnfrmRcptQuerySave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnfrmRcptQuerySave.Click
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(cs)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into TicketInfo(TicketNo, Date, CustNum, CustName, Address, ContNum, Email, AptDate) Values (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@0", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(lblRcptQueryNo.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = lblRcptQueryDate.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtRcptQueryCustNo.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryName.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryAddress.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryContact.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@6", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryEmail.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@7", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimeRcptQuery.Value
                con.Open()
                retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Saving Table 1", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show($"{retVal} record saved to Table 1.")
    'Save Data to CleintDetails Table.
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(cs)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into CleintDetails(CustNum, CustName, Address, ContNum, Email) Values (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@0", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtRcptQueryCustNo.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryName.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryAddress.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryContact.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtRcptQueryEmail.Text
                con.Open()
                retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Saving Table 2", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show($"{retVal} record saved to Table 2")
    btnfrmRcptQuerySave.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

This is a poorly designed database that requires entering duplicate data in 2 different tables. Get familiar with the concept of Foreign Key.